# Cannot join a virtual machine Windows 10 to server 2019 virtual machine domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

I am working as an IT technician. In order to get some exposure to Hyper-V and Windows Servers.

My supervisor assigned me a project to learn how to install active directory and servers in server manager. I have installed AD and DNS in server manager. Also promoted the server as a domain controller.

Now when I try to make the windows 10 virtual machine a part of the domain. I am getting the following error :

```
DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain "Harry.local":
The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.Harry.local
The following domain controllers were identified by the query: WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local
However, no domain controllers could be contacted.
Common causes of this error include: 
- Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.
- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.
```

Comment: Have you already eliminated the causes suggested in the `Common causes of this error include` section of the error message?

Comment: Try `ping WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local` at the command line and see what happens.

Comment: Esa Jokinen unfortunately no because I am getting hands on experience to servers these days. So have no clue how to respond to those errors. But if you can assist I can try my best.

Comment: #HarryJohnston I tried pinging at the powershell and got the following result.                           ping WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local
Ping request could not find host WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: What happens if you run the same command on the domain controller?

Comment: #Harry I get the following result on the domain controller                               ping WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local

Pinging WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: What about `nslookup WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local` on both the client and the domain controller?

Comment: #Harry following is the result of the command on the client :                      
nslookup  WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local
Server:  Test-DC.Harry.local
Address:  169.254.234.139
*** Test-DC.Harry.local can't find WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local: Non-existent domain

Comment: #Harry Following is the result of the command on the domain controller:                                                              nslookup WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local
Server:  Test-DC.Harry.local
Address:  169.254.234.139
*** Test-DC.Harry.local can't find WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local: Non-existent domain

Comment: Is there more than one domain controller?  What is Test-DC?

Comment: No there is only one domain controller. The thing is the ip address is 169.254.234.139 and when I ping -a 169.254.234.139...........It comes up as Pinging Harry.local [169.254.234.139] with 32 bytes of data:                        When I do ns lookup it comes like this Default Server:  Test-DC.Harry.local
Address:  169.254.234.139

Comment: One more thing I realised the client IP is 169.254.29.129 and the DC IP is 169.254.234.139.     I can ping DC from client machine but when I try to ping 169.254.29.129 from DC server, I am getting the result of request timed out.

Comment: Hey Harry the reason it was showing as Test-DC because when I was trying to solve the issue and was playing around with it. I added a pointer in the reverse look up zone but not I have changed the hostname in the pointer properties as WIN-7M2VT2137NJ.Harry.local.

Comment: You can't ping the client because Windows Firewall is up by default, that's not related to your problem.  But it looks as if the DC is failing to register itself in the DNS, look for NETLOGON event ID 5774 (or any other errors really) in the System event log on the DC.

Comment: I clicked on all servers in the server manager and I saw NETLOGON ID 5781. Also, in DNS events I can see a warning of Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service 4013. In particular, it demonstrates the DNS server is waiting for active directory domain services to signal that the initial synchronization of the directory has been completed................

Comment: Any updates on this Harry??

Answer (score 0):

- Add DNS address in local computer as a gateway.
- Firewall off both client and server
- Check connectivity using `ping` command.

If it is not working please follow the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8LRLkdWwc4